# A second Perch of Kairos is blocking my Rainbow Dragon!

Tags: dragonvale

I've got a perch of kairos in DragonVale, and it's been placed so it's blocking my Rainbow dragon and his pot of Gold.

I can still see the Rainbow dragon, and his habitat, which are both beside the perch of Kairos, but whenever I try and click on them it just selects the Perch of Kairos instead.

I'm fully up to date, and have tried logging in from both an iPad and an iTouch, to no avail.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this so I can get to my rainbow dragon again?

[image: problem with perch of kairos]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and post it here?

Comment: ... How do you have two perches?

Comment: I'm not really sure ;-) I think it's a glitch.... it's actually my kids that play DragonVale, so I'm not 100% sure of the ins and outs of it ;-) They implied that it was lucky/a glitch that they had 2....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting glitch there.  You can try to zoom in as much as possible and try to hit the left boundary crystal or the left side of the rainbow and that might get it for you.  Otherwise you're going to have to report the issue to support.  I'm guessing that they will get rid of the second perch so you'll have to make a call on that.

I'd include this screenshot and your Gamecenter ID.  Support email address is support@backflipstudios.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've emailed Backflip studios but have yet to receive a response. I'll post back here if I do!

Comment: No response yet from Backflip regarding this issue.... FYI!

Comment: Still no response.... Accepting this as answer until something better shows up ;-)

Comment: Backflip got back to me today.... and removed my second perch.... they said it's fixed now, so this is now the best "official" answer!